# Windows 10 Universal Apps

Tags: c#, rss, windows-10-universal

Im a C# dev and recently my company has the need for a RSS news feed with a live tile update (windows 10 only). Im kinda new to the universal apps stuff and was hoping someone can help point me in the right direction. Some good tutorials and possibly samples related to rss feeds.

Also, am I on the right path? Is a universal app what I need or would a classic windows assembly do the trick?

Thanks for any advice. Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Good start. I used to have proper googleing skills... but seems im loosing my touch.